# Get usage statistics in Sandbox

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution, web-analytics, statistics

I'm working in SharePoint 2010 in sandbox solution.

I have a site with lot of subsites and lists.

I need to have statistics of consultation: like how many times this site is visited, how many times a user visit this list. etc.

I could write a client script but I've no idea how to get this information.

It seems that there are not enought deep in the site web analytics report to get this information?